# Editing client PC host file with server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to modify my client PCs connecting to my windows server 2012 host file. Would I use a group policy, execute a script on login ?

For example if I was trying to block everything and allow only google.com?

I imagine that there is probably a better way to do this using GP so if you know a better please suggest it.

All help on how to do this is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have a functioning Windows server and domain, why would you touch the host file at all?  Setup and configure a DNS server.  Please don't needlessly modify the hosts file.

Comment: I fully agree with you, is there a way short of setting up the DNS server to limit site access through GP? For example if I was trying to block everything and allow only google.com?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to allow or block the URL's is to deploy a firewall setup or a proxy setup. Deploying such rules using GPO would only work with Internet Explorer, but not for other browsers. Also, allowing and blocking using GPO can be easily bypassed.

But if you would like to use GPO, then please take a review at the below article.

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-use-group-policy-to-allow-or-block-urls/